# Misterious and random LOAD DATA delays in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Every 4 hours we're csv-loading between 1-15m rows in a table about 100-150m in size. The table is trimmed back to 100m once every 24 hours. Each row is less than 100 bytes. Normally this takes a few minutes:

```
01:22:07 Keys for two_legs disabled. Affected rows: 0 [1 sec.]
01:22:07 Inserting new rows WITHOUT keyword CONCURRENT.
03:33:41 Data copied from /home/csv-tmp/new_two_legs_160613_010554.csv to two_legs. Affected rows: 10432731 [7894 sec.]
03:45:28 Keys for two_legs enabled. Affected rows: 0 [707 sec.]
03:45:28 INSERTED ROWS - 1774435 | REPLACED ROWS - 8658296.
```

Some minutes later, we insert more rows in the same table (which is now even bigger):

```
04:04:07 Keys for two_legs disabled.
04:04:07 Inserting new rows WITHOUT keyword CONCURRENT.
04:05:57 Data copied from /home/csv-tmp/new_two_legs_160613_034534.csv to two_legs. Affected rows: 11363628 [110 sec.]
04:11:40 Keys for two_legs enabled. Affected rows: 0 [343 sec.]
04:11:40 INSERTED ROWS - 1887702 | REPLACED ROWS - 9475926.
```

The mysql QUERIES used are:

```
ALTER TABLE $table DISABLE KEYS

LOAD DATA $c_piece LOCAL INFILE '$path' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE $table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
($fields)

ALTER TABLE $table ENABLE KEYS
```

I've been struggling with this for a while, to no avail. There is no any delay with server itself such as high traffic peaks; everything happens in the middle of local night when clients do not request much. Sometimes there are no delays for a few days, sometimes there are every day. How to debug this?

Comment: I was waiting for this comment. Thanks. Next?

Comment: It's just a secret wrapper (I'm trying to hide what we use).

Comment: If you're stuck with this interface for whatever reason, sorry to hear that. Otherwise, *fix it*. PHP 7 got rid of this thing so you'll have to do it eventually, this code won't run on the current version. Those "secret wrappers" often hide problems so they're best avoided.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question. The issue is really not there, because everything works well except this CSV insertion. It can be something with mysql database settings. Or something else strange. But not the chosen PHP interface. This is a mySQL question.

Comment: If you're trying to diagnose a performance problem have you monitored server IO? CPU load? Do you have any metrics here as to what might be slowing it down? MySQL's pretty terrible about dealing with tables that have high churn (additions/deletions) so you may need to `OPTIMIZE TABLE` once in a while, as painful as that is.

Comment: If it's just a MySQL question, post a minimal example of what you're doing in MySQL alone. The PHP layer may not be relevant, but you've put it here and all I see is hazards. Getting to the bottom of a problem often involves a process of elimination, so if this still occurs *without* PHP that's an important discovery.

Comment: Also worth checking is your InnoDB settings, as I hope you're using InnoDB. It's an engine that's not very well tuned by default but [isn't that hard to configure properly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb.html). The biggest gains come from throwing memory at [`innodb_buffer_pool_size`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size).

Comment: It takes 2 hours and 20 minutes with key updates, no

Comment: The table in question is MyIsam and it has been partitioned into ~30 partititons.